# Masking a scrolling text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a simple application with text animations and videos as background.

It's really similar to a simple LED scrolling text and I'm using the animations framework of WPF for this (Storyboards and timelines).

My text comes from the right side and finishes animation to the left side, thus it is visible for the entire width of the window.

Now, what if I want to display this text only in a specific rectangle of the window? The text would normally come from the right and finish to the left, but should be visible only when passing through this rectangle. Imagine it like a "rectangle hole" in the background where the text is shown.

I hope I have been straightforward in my explanation!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it an opacity mask you're after?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbeniwal321/implementing-opacity-masks-in-wpf/

Obviously you won't be using gradients of opacity as seen in the article - you'll use a more strict rectangle outline and play your animation as usual - using the bounds of the mask as the boundaries of your animation.

Answer (score 1):

Text in a Canvas. Set the size and position of your Canvas to be your rectangle hole. With clipping on, when the text is outside the Canvas, it will not show. You just animate Canvas.Left attached property on your text.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Both your answers were good but I have chosen as correct the one I have used for my problem :)